# Finding all values from one column within another column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to iterate through all values in a column Keyword in a table `Keyword_Table` and search for these values within a column
`Block_of_Text` in another table `Raw_Text`. The Keywords from `Keyword_Table` are embedded within a large amount of text in `Raw_Text.Block_of_Text`. Another important note is that the `Keyword_Table` is about 4000 records large and the table `Raw_Text` is about 4,000,000 records. In the end, I would like to have output that would contain a column with the value from `Keyword_Table.Keyword` and the full `Raw_Text.Block_of_Text` value containing the corresponding value from `Keyword_Table.Keyword`.
**There are no values in common between the two tables so I can't use joins I don't think.**

Currently I am trying to use this code but given the scale of the tables it is extremely inefficient. I added a column called `Corresponding_Keyword` to `Raw_Tex`t

```
UPDATE [Raw_Text]
SET Corresponding_Keyword =
(
CASE
WHEN Block_of_Text LIKE CONCAT('%','XXXX','%')  Then 'XXXX'
WHEN Block_of_Text LIKE CONCAT('%','YYYY','%')  Then 'YYYY'
WHEN Block_of_Text LIKE CONCAT('%','ZZZZ','%')  Then 'ZZZZ'
END
)
```

But in this situation it is not 3 Cases, but 4000. So obviously this solution is unreasonable. Does anyone have any insight on how I may best handle this situation. The lack of a field to join seems like a problem for me but is this just intrinsically difficult given the nature of the task with large tables? Thanks.

Comment: What value do you want in `Corresponding_Keyword` if there are multiple keywords e.g. `Block_of_Text` contains the all the values `XXXX`, `YYYY` and `ZZZZ`?

Comment: There is no efficient solution to this in T-SQL, unless you move to things like full-text search. The problem is that one way or another 4000 `LIKE`s are going to have to happen, and that isn't fast, no matter how you write the query. The query itself could be something like `WITH T AS (SELECT *, (SELECT TOP(1) Keyword FROM Keyword_Table WHERE Block_of_Text LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%' ORDER BY Keyword) AS Lookup_Keyword FROM Raw_Text) UPDATE T SET Corresponding_Keyword = Lookup_Keyword` (among other approaches), but, as mentioned, not fast.

Comment: If there are multiple matched keywords then I would be happy with the last keyword matched to be the one in Corresponding_Keyword. As for the point that this isn't going to be fast that is what I expected. I appreciate the input

Comment: what is the data type of "Block_of_Text" and its max length?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a JOIN like this should work, I am not sure about the performance though:

```
SELECT kw.Keyword, t.Block_of_Text
FROM Keyword_Table kw
JOIN Raw_Text t ON t.Block_of_Text LIKE '%' + kw.Keyword + '%'
```